# Error retrieving JSON data from Webhose API in Python

Tags: python, json, webhose

I am a beginner in Python and am trying to use the webhose.io API to collect data from the web. The problem is that this crawler retrieves 100 objects from one JSON at a time, i.e., to retrieve 500 data, it is necessary to make 5 requests. When I use the API, I am not able to collect all the data at once. I was able to collect the first 100 results, but when going to the next request, an error occurs, the first post is repeated. Follow the code:

```
import webhoseio
webhoseio.config(token="Xxxxx")
query_params = {
    "q": "trump:english",
    "ts": "1498538579353",
    "sort": "crawled"
}
output = webhoseio.query("filterWebContent", query_params)


x = 0

for var in output['posts']:
    print output['posts'][x]['text']
    print output['posts'][x]['published']
    if output['posts'] is None:
        output = webhoseio.get_next()
        x = 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error? Add the traceback

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
while output['posts']:
    for var in output['posts']:
        print output['posts'][0]['text']
        print output['posts'][0]['published']

    output = webhoseio.get_next()
```